# Issue with CASE statement not giving correct value

Tags: sql

I am using the following CASE statement in SQL Developer:

```sql
CASE  
  WHEN ([Medication]="N") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND ([Original Units] IS NOT NULL) THEN "Y" 
  WHEN ([Medication]="N") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND ([Original Units] IS NULL) THEN "N" 
  WHEN ([Medication]="Y") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND ([Original Units] IS NOT NULL) THEN "N" 
  WHEN ([Medication]="Y") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND ([Original Units] IS NULL) THEN "Y" 
END
```

My results are empty when I should at least get `N`.

Comment: What should happen when the Name is not STYMES or the Medication field contains something other than N or Y (e.g., 1, 0, NULL, TRUE, FALSE, yak)?

Comment: When the name is not STYMES  and medication field contains Y then I would expect to receive a Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to get an 'N' when your other conditions are not met, you can use the ELSE keyword, as in:

```
case  
  when ([Medication]="N") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND([Original Units] is not null) then "Y" 
  when ([Medication]="N") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND([Original Units] is null) then "N" 
  when ([Medication]="Y") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND([Original Units] is not null) then "N" 
  when ([Medication]="Y") AND ([Name]="STYMES") AND([Original Units] is null) then "Y" 
  else "N"
end
```